# Using SQL to multiple condition to get value

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

We have multiple invoice transaction with line type bases of catalog and non catalog item then each catalog and non catalog item have respective invoice line number series, sometime PO line number available with similar number to map respective catalog items.

| Invoice ID | Line Type | Invoice Line Number | PO Line Number | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Non-Catalog Item | 1 |  | 54000 |
| 123 | CGST | 2 |  | 100 |
| 123 | IGST | 3 |  | 50 |
| 456 | Catalog Item | 1 | 2 | 155000 |
| 456 | CGST | 2 | 2 | 13500 |
| 456 | IGST | 3 | 2 | 1040 |

We are looking to get each catalog and non catalog item line update separately and map respective CGST and IGST value in single row.

Desire result:

| Invoice ID | Line Type | Invoice Line Number | SUM | CGST | IGST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Non-Catalog Item | 1 | 54000 | 100 | 50 |
| 456 | Catalog Item | 1 | 155000 | 13500 | 1040 |

Please help us to resolve these through SQL. Especially the one below:

[image]

Comment: Could you tag the RDBMS (oracle, sql server ...) you are using ?

Comment: if possible provide in RDBMS as MS Sql server.

Comment: the Invoice Line Number is always set to 1 for both Non-Catalog and Catalog items?

Comment: Check out sql server pivots, it's pretty cool

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: Your title says with SQL so have removed VBA tag, a question needs to be answerable in a single technology else how would select an answer when provided with solutions in multiple?

Comment: May You use a TSQL procedure to do this? that will make it possible to return what You wish using multiple statements but looking like one from the outside

Comment: See @siggemannen you can just use a PIVOT on the InvoiceID. The InvoiceLineNumber seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: @TeunKruijer I have attached scenario in picture now. these scenario pivot will not effective. we have to segregate each catalog or non catalog and find sequence of GST to map.

Comment: Please share your data as text not image, so it can be easy for us to help you

Comment: insert into invoices values 
(569052, 'Non-Catalog Item', 1, NULL, 13500),
(569052, 'IGST', 2, NULL, 1341),
(569052, 'Catalog Item', 3, NULL, 670700),
(569052, 'CGST', 4, NULL, 1000),
(569052, 'Non-Catalog Item', 5, NULL, 2000),
(569052, 'IGST', 6, NULL, 100),
(569052, 'Non-Catalog Item', 7, NULL, 1000),
(569052, 'CGST', 8, NULL, 300);

Comment: the last problem was added last minute and not even written properly in the question. its still a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a *gap and island* problem  that can be addressed by employing a running total to allocate a unique identifier to each group :

```
with cte as (
  select *, sum(case when LineType in ('Non-Catalog Item', 'Catalog Item') then 1 else 0 end) 
            over (partition by InvoiceID order by InvoiceNumber) as grp,
            case when LineType in ('Non-Catalog Item', 'Catalog Item') then 1 else 0 end as catalog_flag
  from invoices
)
select InvoiceID, max(case when catalog_flag = 1 then LineType end) as LineType, 
                  max(case when catalog_flag = 1 then InvoiceNumber end) as InvoiceNumber, 
                  sum(case when catalog_flag = 1 then sum end ) as Amount,
                  sum(case when LineType = 'IGST' then sum end ) as IGST,
                  sum(case when LineType = 'CGST' then sum end ) as CGST
from cte c
group by InvoiceID, grp
```

Results :

```
InvoiceID   LineType        InvoiceNumber   Amount  IGST    CGST
569052  Non-Catalog Item    1               13500   1341    null
569052  Catalog Item        3               670700  null    1000
569052  Non-Catalog Item    5               2000    100     null
569052  Non-Catalog Item    7               1000    null    300
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/PBAzXZ9v)

Comment: Thank you so much Its help me a lot... Its mindblowing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "grouping" by counting how often the Line types you're interested in occurs in the rows:

```sql
SELECT  [Invoice ID], MIN([Invoice Line Number]) AS [Line Number]
,   MAX(CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN [Line Type] END) AS [Line Type]
,   sum(CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN SUM ELSE 0 END) AS SUM
,   sum(CASE WHEN "Line Type" = 'CGST' THEN SUM ELSE 0 END) AS CGST
,   sum(CASE WHEN "Line Type" = 'IGST' THEN SUM ELSE 0 END) AS IGST
FROM    (
    SELECT  *
    ,   SUM(flag) OVER(PARTITION BY [Invoice ID] ORDER BY [Invoice Line Number] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS groupRow
    FROM
    (
        VALUES  (123, N'Non-Catalog Item', 1, NULL, 54000)
        ,   (123, N'CGST', 2, NULL, 100)
        ,   (123, N'IGST', 3, NULL, 50)
        ,   (123, N'Non-Catalog Item', 4, NULL, 54000)
        ,   (123, N'CGST', 5, NULL, 100)
        ,   (123, N'Catalog Item', 6, NULL, 54000)
        ,   (123, N'CGST', 7, NULL, 100)
        ,   (456, N'Catalog Item', 1, 2, 155000)
        ,   (456, N'CGST', 2, 2, 13500)
        ,   (456, N'IGST', 3, 2, 1040)
    ) t ([Invoice ID],[Line Type],[Invoice Line Number],[PO Line Number],SUM)
    CROSS apply (
            SELECT  CASE WHEN [line type] IN ('Non-Catalog Item', 'Catalog Item') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flag
        ) f
    ) x
GROUP BY [Invoice ID], [groupRow]
ORDER BY x.[Invoice ID], [Line Number]
```

The "flag" is summarized which creates a new group row which contains Item + CGST/IGST.
Then you need to pivot the values by doing some conditional aggregation.

Output:

| Invoice ID | Line Number | Line Type | SUM | CGST | IGST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | Non-Catalog Item | 54000 | 100 | 50 |
| 123 | 4 | Non-Catalog Item | 54000 | 100 | 0 |
| 123 | 6 | Catalog Item | 54000 | 100 | 0 |
| 456 | 1 | Catalog Item | 155000 | 13500 | 1040 |